# Does a script run on crontab have admin privileges?

Tags: python, cron, redhat

If I run my Python script on a crontab task, does it get admin access?
If not, how can I get it run with a specific user privileges? In that case, what is the most secure way to give user and pwd information?

Comment: It depends whether you add to your user `crontab` or `root's` crontab.

Comment: Ok, so the script get the crontab user privileges. But, how can I change those privileges ? I guess I need to exec someting like su - user in my script. In that case how to give the pwd securily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specific to whoever called crontab -e. Whichever user at the time.

So

```
sudo crontab -e
```

runs everything since it is owned by the sudoers group.

But if you don't use sudo, then crontab will be installed for whatever user called it and thus only have the permissions that user has.